# Keeping User Customized Tab Bar Items

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

My tab bar app uses the built in "more" tab where you can customize the tab bar with different items, but When the app quits or shuts down after not being used for a while, the user's customized tab bar changes back to its default settings. I was wondering if there was any way of keeping the customization for ever. I am a novice coder, so any and all code would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To save user preferences you can use [NSUserDefaults class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which is rather simple to use and will do the job you want.

You have to save user preferences when he chooses them:

```
#define kUserTabBarPreferences @"TabBarUserPreferences"

NSDictionary *tabBarPreferences = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:kUserTabBarPreferences];
if (nil == tabBarPreferences) {
// Initialize a new dictionary
}
// Set New preferences in NSDictionary
...
//Save new preferences
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:tabBarPreferences forKey:kUserTabBarPreferences];
```

When you application is launched, get preferences frome `NSUSerDefaults`:

```
NSDictionary *tabBarPreferences = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] kUserTabBarPreferences];
```

And change your application tab bar just as your user prefer it.

Comment: Can you help me with the code? I am a beginner and I dont understand much of it...

Comment: When you call synchronize method it is saved to disk. You can read this link to get complete documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize

Comment: The first sample in the method you use to customize your application tab bar. The seconde sample in the viewDidLoad method of the UIViewController you want to customize with user preferences

Comment: So I put the first part in my app delegate in the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" part, and the second in my tab bar controller in the view did load part. Is there any other code i need?

Comment: Please, check out this more complete tutorial http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/